# Does Apache Strom field grouping work across multiple workers?

Tags: java, apache, apache-storm

I can see how hashing the field contents and task Id together is used to keep all tuples with the same value in a field going to the same bolt task. However, how can theis be guarenteed if there is more than one worker? Surely bolt tasks are not shared between workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of tasks is fixed when a Topology is created and never changes. Rebalance commands can change which executors host a task but they are not destroyed, therefore tuples with the same field values will always go to the same task regardless of which worker process or executor it is on.

You may have already seen this but [this](https://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html) is a good explanation of Storm's parallelism and provides a bit more detail.